# Elevating Java permissions through code using SecurityManager

Tags: java, security, permissions, jnlp

I have written a desktop Java application and I am looking to redeploy it using Java Web Start. I have analysed my code and 99% can be run with "sandbox" permissions, but I have a couple of functions which would require "all-permissions". These functions aren't used that often, but they are still critical functions that I need to provide.

Instead of requesting "all-permissions" in my JAR for something which probably won't be used most of the time, is it possible to have "sandbox" permissions and then elevate to "all-permissions" through code for the duration of these functions? I would expect the user to have to approve this through a dialog - I am not looking to bypass the security of Java.

I have found there is the JNLP API which provides the FileOpenService and FileSaveService, which is similar to what I am after, but it only appears to deal with a few scenarios. I am looking for a way to elevate my permissions to be able to use Desktop.getDesktop.browse().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JNLP API also offers a  basic service for opening a URI in the default browser.

Comment: Ok, I should have read the JNLP API documentation in full, but I should have also included another point in my question. The file I wish to view in the browser is cached in the JAR and I write it to a temporary file using File.createTempFile(). The createTempFile() method is throwing a permissions exception (as expected).

Comment: *"..The file I wish to view in the browser .. is cached in the JAR"*  What in that HTML (presumably) cannot be displayed by a [`JEditorPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JEditorPane.html) or (better) the Java FX based [`WebView`](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/web/WebView.html)?  Either can apparently handle loading HTML from URL (1st from experience, 2nd from the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html#load%28java.lang.String%29)), which will save the need to write it first to `File`.

Comment: It is HTML5 and yes I would love to use JavaFX to display it, but I need to provide backwards compatibility with JRE 1.6. It is definitely something I want to move towards in the future.

Comment: Before 1.7, Java-FX was available as an 'add on' API.  Just add it to the run-time class-path, and the code should be good to go.  (I guess you've already realized that `JEditorPane` is designed for (a subset of) HTML 3.2, and is therefore not up to displaying HTML 5.)

Comment: I think you have answered my question, in the sense that, the JNLP API is limited in the methods it provides and doesn't cover all scenarios that require "all-permissions". For these scenarios, I either need to request "all-permissions" in the Manifest or look to redesign my code so it does use something provided via the JNLP API. I suppose I was looking for the ability to instantiate a new SecurityManager() with higher permissions to run a specific task. However, I do feel there should be some middle ground between "sandbox" and "all-permissions", maybe in the future.

Comment: *"However, I do feel there should be some middle ground between "sandbox" and "all-permissions", maybe in the future."*  There is!  It is known as `j2ee-application-client-permissions`.  AFAIR it allows JNLP API calls to be made without further prompt (a sand boxed app. would prompt the user when the app. goes to use those services) and removes the floating warning icon that accompanies sand-boxed code.

Comment: BTW - I have the sneaking suspicion you will not be ably to get this to work using the JNLP API services.  True it offeres a `FileSaveService` and a `BasicService` method to show an URL in the browser, but it will not be possible to use them together.  The basic reason is that the `FileContents` object (by which you might write out the HTML 5) will not allow the app. to know the location of the created (or read) file, so we cannot form an URL for it, to pass to the browser.  Conversely, the browser cannot show the content of the Jar, even if we can form an URL to it.